# Regular expression of valid floating point numbers

Tags: regex

I'm trying to make regular expression of valid floating point numbers which accept only significant zeros.
but i think i am making a mistake, can anyone please help?

[-+]?([0-9]*.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)

I am expecting it to return all valid floating point which accept only significant zeros
[-+]?([0-9]*.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)

Comment: What exactly, in your goal statement, makes a zero "significant"? Is the 0 in 08.13? What about 0.13? Or 1.30? If "significant" means that removing the 0 leads to a different value, then the last two are insignificant, since .13 and 1.3 are the same calues, respectively. Yet I venture to say that most programmers would be surprised to find that 0.13 and 1.30 were illegal representations.

Comment: Anyway, `[0-9]+` certainly accepts inputs  with leading zeros. So if you wanted to exclude leading zeros, you'd need a slightly more complicated subexpression.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I have correctly understood your question, but I think you just forgot to escape the `.` character.

In fact, the regex you are proposing here would match string like "5a43" or even "90#1".

In order to correct this problem, you need to place a backslash (`\`) before the point. (The point like that corresponds to any character, except a line-break.)

The corrected regex would finally be : `[-+]?([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)`.